# the function not returning any value

Tags: c, arrays

This is my code and its not working .

if the arr in the prev position is bigger or smaller from the follow one if its bigger for all the array so i should return the value 1

if in some point in the array the prev position of the arr is bigger then then follow one so its should return the value 0 thank for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int Up_array(int *arr,int Size )
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<Size;i++)

        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(arr[i] <= arr[i+1]) 
        {
            return 1;
        }   
}       

void main ()
{
int *arr,Size,i;

    printf("please enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&Size);
    arr=(int*)malloc(Size*sizeof(int));
    printf("please enter the array\n");
    for (i=0; i<Size ;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    Up_array(arr,Size);
    free(arr);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), learn to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consult your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Do you have a *specific* question for us?

Comment: `arr[i+1]` could invoke UB as at some point it will be equivalent to `arr[Size]` which is out of bounds. Although given the current checks, the whole array is not checked just the first two elements, move `return 1;` out of the loop and get rid of the `else if`, and change the loop to `for(i=0;i<Size-1;i++)`. I think that'll do what you want but it's really hard to tell from the question

Comment: Your function just checks the first 2 elements of the array, since it returns in both branches of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return in the `else` block. This will immediately return `1` as soon as it finds two elements that are increasing, it won't check the rest of the array. As a result, your function just checks the first two elements of the array.

Instead, wait until you get through the entire array. If you didn't return `0` inside the loop, it means that all the elements were ascending, so then you can return `1`.

Also, you need to avoid accessing outside the array, so you need to stop the array when `i` is `Size - 2`, so that `arr[i+1]` is still inside the array.

```
int Up_array(int *arr,int Size )
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<Size-1;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And in general, when the condition in `else if` is the exact opposite of the `if` condition, you should just use `else`, not `else if`.

Answer (score -1):

Almost right. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int up_array(int *arr,int Size )
{    
    // Checking corner case where Size = 1 (no index out of bound)
    if(Size > 1) {
        for(int i=0; i<Size-1; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
                return 0;
            } 
        }   
    }
    return 1;
}       

int main ()
{
    int *arr,Size;

    printf("Please enter the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&Size);
    arr=(int*)malloc(Size*sizeof(int));
    printf("Please enter the array (press enter after any number)\n");
    for (int i=0; i<Size ;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Result %d", Up_array(arr,Size));

    free(arr);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `if(Size > 1)`, since the `for()` condition will fail immediately and the loop will never execute.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Just dumping code without an explanation is not considered a good answer. Please explain *how* and *why* you did whatever you did.

Comment: @HermannDöppes would you please quote the part in the [TOUR](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which actually suggest what you said?

Comment: @Michi I never claimed the existence of such a part. Those are two different sentences talking about different things.

Comment: @HermannDöppes But you just Down Voted an Answer  (or you didn't?) because of that.

Comment: guys its still not working for me.. there no errors and still not returning nothing

Comment: @HaiVaknin This Answer has so many problems, no wonder is not Working.

Comment: @HaiVaknin Please append your amended code to your question. I suspect you're simply not printing the return value, but only one way to know for sure :)

Comment: @HaiVaknin Just for curiosity, [Does this work for you](http://ideone.com/KZfL3W)?